# What is the grammar of "I'm home"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Why do we often say "I'm home" rather than "I'm at home"? How is the former even grammatically correct? Should this be thought of as a use of a "phrasal verb", "to be home"?

(We don't say "I'm beach" or "I'm gym"... Similarly we say "Go home" but not "Go work"...)

Are there other examples of this pattern of dropping an otherwise required preposition?

Comment: There are a few words denoting habitual places that don't require prepositions. _Home_ is one; _I'm home_ usually is uttered on entering, and means "I'm returning to my home"; _I'm at home_ usually means "I am in my home now, not elsewhere". Short sentences usually mask big contexts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth not really, I'm asking about the actual grammar of this phrase.

Comment: Many wives have told their husbands "Go work!"

Comment: (1) It's grammatical. (2) It's a relict from earlier 'I'm a-home' (the best I can reproduce this simply) where 'a-home' corresponds to a prepositional phrase (cf 'I'm in Manchester / on the train / at the doctor's / over in France ...). The marking distinguishing the erstwhile PP from the noun has been lost. (3) This doesn't happen with say _school, doctor's, France, [the] train_ ... you still need the overt preposition.  (4) This _has_ been said before.